# Complex Fourier Series does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the value of the following summation:

$$ \sum_{n=-2}^2 c_n $$

Such that $ c_n $ are the complex Fourier coefficents for:

$$ f(x)=e^\frac{ix}{2} : x \in [-\pi, \pi]$$

---

Here is the attempt:

$$ c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^\frac{ix}{2}e^{-inx} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \biggl[\frac{e^{ix(\frac{1}{2}-n)}}{\frac{1}{2}-n}\biggr]^\pi_{-\pi} $$

I evaluated $ e^{ix(\frac{1}{2}-n)} $ on the complex unit circle for $\pm\pi$ and determined them to both be the same value, thus:

$$ c_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(\frac{1}{2}-n)} : n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

With this, I was able to find the summation:

$$ \sum_{n=-2}^2 c_n = \frac{2}{5\pi}-\frac{2}{3\pi}+ \frac{1}{2\pi}+ \frac{1}{2\pi} -\frac{3}{2\pi} $$

Here's the interesting part- using $c_n$ in the actual function it's supposed to represent (I wanted to check my $c_n$ is correct) :

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx}  $$

returns "Series does not converge" on Wolfram Alpha. So I assume that I've made a mistake somewhere in calculating $c_n$, is this true?

Comment: Reliance on wolfram alpha bad, actually learning math good. Your computation is actually correct, and then group terms with $n, -n$ together and get the quadratic inverse estimation that proves absolute convergence. The one subtle point where wolfram and your reliance on it rather than on learning Fourier theory fails is that the Fourier partial sums are specified symmetric so you can group as noted, while the double series is not absolute convergent and not even convergent if you use arbitrary partial sums

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads up. Wolfram hasn't failed me before, and it's good to know that it wasn't a silly mistake like a double negative somewhere.

Comment: @Conrad The doubly infinite series does converge conditionally for $-\pi < x < \pi$, that is,
$$\lim_{(n_1, n_2) \to (-\infty, \infty)}
\sum_{n = n_1}^{n_2} c_n e^{i n x}$$
exists by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: yes that's true but it is not convergent at $\pi$ and that's why I think Wolfram flagged it as non-convergent